# Mongo operator $pull not working (Meteor.js)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

meteor mongo console (working):

```
db.projects.update({ _id: "uA2HeAZuggESbocxK"}, {$pull: {views: { _id: 'ufy3XCRQfxarHjbsy'}}})
```

meteor shell console (not working):

```
Projects.update({ _id: "uA2HeAZuggESbocxK"}, {$pull: {views: { _id: 'ufy3XCRQfxarHjbsy'}}})
```

First one works fine and removes object from array, second one ain't. Just silently without errors doing nothing.
What I am doing wrong? Is there an alternative to remove object from array in Mongo using Meteor.methods ?

Comment: Did you work around this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to manually edit the array, and then re-assign it

Comment: Could it be that you're using collection2 with an autovalue in a field of the array elements? That was my problem. In autovalue you have to distinguish the case where it's a pull, insert and so on.

Comment: This post provides more detail on what @NicolaMarcacciRossi describes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853063/pull-an-entry-from-an-array-via-meteor

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
var idsKeyName = "views";
var arr_views = {};
arr_views[idsKeyName] = { _id: 'ufy3XCRQfxarHjbsy'}; 

db.projects.update({ _id: "uA2HeAZuggESbocxK"}, {$pull: arr_views})
```

Thanks

Comment: The question clearly states that he is able to `$pull` in the meteor mongo console. A helpful answer should involve the meteor shell console or Meteor.methods approach.