# Pull an entry from an array via Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I've the following (simplified) SimpleSchema schema in my Meteor 1.1.0.2 app:

```js
Tickers.attachSchema(
    new SimpleSchema({
        entries: {
            type: [TickerEntries],
            defaultValue: [],
            optional: true
        }
    })
);

TickerEntries = new SimpleSchema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden",
            label: false,
            readonly: true
        },
        optional: true,
        autoValue: function () {
            if (!this.isSet) {
                return new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID()._str;
            }
        }
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Text'
    }
};
```

In the database I do have the following entries:

```js
{
    "_id" : "ZcEvq9viGQ3uQ3QnT",
    "entries" : [
        {
            "text" : "a",
            "id" : "fc29774dadd7b37ee0dc5e3e"
        },
        {
            "text" : "b",
            "id" : "8171c4dbcc71052a8c6a38fb"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to remove one entry in the entries array specified by an ID.

If I execute the following command in the meteor-mongodb-shell it works without problems:

```js
db.Tickers.update({_id:"3TKgHKkGnzgfwqYHY"}, {"$pull":{"entries": {"id":"8171c4dbcc71052a8c6a38fb"}}})
```

But the problem is, that if I'm going to do the same from within Meteor, it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```js
Tickers.update({id: '3TKgHKkGnzgfwqYHY'}, {$pull: {'entries': {'id': '8171c4dbcc71052a8c6a38fb'}}});
```

I've also tried the following:

```js
Tickers.update('3TKgHKkGnzgfwqYHY', {$pull: {'entries': {'id': '8171c4dbcc71052a8c6a38fb'}}});
```

None of these commands give me an error, but they don't remove anything from my document.

Could it be possible, that the `$pull` command isn't supported properly or do I have made a mistake somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've found the problem, which couldn't be seen in my description, because I've simplified my schema. In my app there's an additional attribute `timestamp` in `TickerEntries`:

```js
TickerEntries = new SimpleSchema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        autoValue: function () {
            if (!this.isSet) {
                return new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID()._str;
            }
        }
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        label: 'Minute',
        optional: true,
        autoValue: function () {
            if (!this.isSet) { // this check here is necessary!
                return new Date();
            }
        }
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Text'
    }
});
```

Thanks to the hint from Kyll, I've created a Meteorpad and found out, that the `autovalue` function is causing the problems.

I've now changed the function to the following code:

```js
autoValue: function () {
    if (!this.isSet && this.operator !== "$pull") { // this check here is necessary!
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

And now it is working. It seems, that returning a autovalue-value in the case of pulling an item/object, it cancels the pull operation, as the value isn't set to the returned value (so the timestamp attribute keeps the old value but isn't pulled).

Here's the according Meteorpad to test it (simply comment out the check for the operator in the autovalue function): http://meteorpad.com/pad/LLC3qeph66pAEFsrB/Leaderboard

Thank you all for your help, all your posts were very helpful to me!

Comment: I suggest drafting up a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/) to show your issue (create the DB, add schemas, populate it, try to remove and show the failure). Another point: Does removing the attached schemas change anything to your issue? If not you may want to remove them from the question altogether, as it is now I don't really know if the schemas hold any importance or not. Finally, congratulations on the format and cleanness of your post! If you add the [tag:javascript] tag to your question it will automatically add colours to the code.

Comment: I suggest you have made a mistake or have a configuration error or conflict somewhere. I have submitted an answer that shows a fully working case. It should help narrow down any issues you might have if something else is interferring with the expected behavior of `$pull`

Comment: Fixed our issues - autovalue was blocking $pull. Thank you for the thorough question and answer @reini122.

Comment: Just to clarify: I had the exact same issue, but I also had to add "if (!this.isSet && this.operator !== "$pull")" on my the "autovalue" of the "id" to make everything work.
Great job to find that out !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a basic meteor application, I call "bunk" on this. If you create a brand new project and simply define the collection, then the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator works as expected:

**Console:**

```js
meteor create tickets
cd tickets
meteor run
```

Then open up a shell and insert your data:

```js
meteor mongo

> db.tickets.insert(data)   // exactly your data in the question
```

Then just produce some basic code and template:

**tickers.js**

```js
Tickers = new Meteor.Collection("tickers");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.body.helpers({
    "tickers": function() {
      return Tickers.find({});
    }
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

**tickers.html**

```js
<head>
  <title>tickers</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  <ul>
    {{#each tickers}}
      {{> ticker}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

</body>

<template name="ticker">
  <li>
    {{_id}}
    <ul>
      {{#each entries}}
        {{> entry }}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="entry">
  <li>{{ id }} - {{text}}</li>
</template>
```

The application should be running fine, so in your browser console do the `.update()` (indented for reading):

```js
Tickers.update(
    { "_id": "ZcEvq9viGQ3uQ3QnT" },
    { "$pull": { "entries": { "id": "fc29774dadd7b37ee0dc5e3e" } }}
)
```

And the item is removed from entries and the page is refreshed without the item. So all gone, just as expected.

Even adding the [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) packages, makes no difference here:

```js
 meteor add aldeed:simple-schema
 meteor add aldeed:collection2
```

**tickers.js**

```js
Tickers = new Meteor.Collection("tickers");

TickerEntries = new SimpleSchema({
  "id": {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (!this.isSet) {
        return new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID()._str
      }
    }
  },
  "text": {
    type: String
  }
});

Tickers.attachSchema(
  new SimpleSchema({
    entries: { type: [TickerEntries] }
  })
);


if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.body.helpers({
    "tickers": function() {
      return Tickers.find({});
    }
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Re-initialize the data and run the same command in the browser console and everything stays the same.

Check this or any typing mistakes in your own operations or other differences for a clue as to why this does not work for you.

I would suggest this strongly, as "starting fresh" like this shows the expected behavior, and if you are seeing different behavior then it is likely an issue with another plugin you have installed.

But generally, this works.

Comment: Thanks for this clean and extensive example! :-)

Comment: @reini122 I really hope there is something in here that "solved" the issue, but otherwise my intention was to show what the basic packages I could deem from your question respond like. Should you otherwise find a conflict then please feel free to notify me of the bug report. StackOverflow comments can be cleaned up later, but I have a personal interest if there is a package conflict causing the problem to make some intervention to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have already solved my issue and edited my original question with the solution. I hope this is clear. I've also added a Meteorpad to simulate the problem, but it is definitive a problem of SimpleSchema, because autovalue stops the pull operator from working in the case of the timestamp field, but a similar code in the ID field doesn't break the functionality.

Comment: reini122, actually for me autoValue on id of subschema also broke the $pull functionality. fixed with your workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, if someone else is looking for an answer.

If you are usein SimpleSchema, you have two options:
the array field should be marked as optional

```
arr: {
 type:Array,
 optional:true
}
```

Or use `getAutoValues: false` in update-query.

```
Coll.update({}, {$pull: {arr: ''}}, {getAutoValues: false});
```