# $push in embedded array Meteor collection2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

In a Meteor project , and I'm using [collection2 package] 
I have the  following collection2 Schema:

```
  var schema =  new SimpleSchema ({
    comments: {
        type: [{text: String, createdAt: Date}],
        optional: true
     }})
```

And when I use this query in Meteor method :

```
Articles.update({_id: articleId}, {$push: {comments: {text: "yryd"}}})
```

It insert a blank object in comments array ... 
OK there is no problem in this query cause i run it in mongo terminal and all thing seems good and the insert operation done
What  is the problem in your opinion?

Comment: Related: [Pull an entry from an array via Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31869196/5031275) which is another question using SimpleSchema and Collection2. See the examples in the answer for how this should be working. In short, you have done something different to what is done there and that is your problem. In fact, what is your problem? You do not really say what is wrong. Other than of course the "createdAt" does not seem valid here. I think you meant another field called "createdAt" with a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema basically appears to be incorrect for what you want to do here. It most likely needs to look something like this:

```
Articles new Meteor.collection("articles");

CommentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    "text": { type: String },
    "createdAt": { type: Date, defaultValue: Date.now }
});

Articles.attachSchema(
    new SimpleSchema({
        "comments": [CommentsSchema]
    })
);
```

Then when you add in new things your schema types are verified for the "text" field being present, and fields like "createdAt" are added to the sub-document within the array entry automatically.